Stop words for elastic enterprise search
Is there a way to configure or at least make elastic enterprise search respect stop words in its search.
my example search i would expect it to add filter but there is no documentation about it.
      const searchRequest: SearchRequest = {
        engine_name: engineName,
        body: {
          query: requestData.query,

          page: {
            current: requestData.current,
            size: requestData.size,
          },
          search_fields: {
            html_content: { weight: 10 },
            title: { weight: 0 },
            provider: { weight: 0 },
            user_id: { weight: 0 },
            file_id: { weight: 0 },
          },
          filters: {
            user_id: token.uid,
          },
        },
      };
      const searchResponse = await client.app.search(searchRequest);

